# Q-value of beta decay in different forms

Tags: radioactivity

Related to this previous post of mine [The Beta Decay equation proper balancing](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/703513/297949) , is it true that Q-value of beta decay reaction can be written in any of these two ways ?
$Q $= ${m _{X}}(_{Z}^{A}\mathrm{X})-m_{X'}(_{Z+1}^{A} \mathrm{X}^{'})$ or
$ Q$ = ${m _{X}}(_{Z}^{A}\mathrm{X})-m_{X'^+}(_{Z+1}^{A} \mathrm{X}^{'+})$

Comment: It seems like Sean's answer that you linked to answers your question. Do you not believe Sean's answer?

Comment: Sir i am just now seeing it and i posted this question before Sean sir posted it